# Custom Contact Form in Partials and use in Static Pages plugin

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend, octobercms-plugins, october-partial

I have used [OctoberCMS](http://octobercms.com/), [Static Pages](http://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-pages) plugin, through which I am creating Static Pages.

The thing is, I have created one contact form in Partial like below.

*contactform_snippet.htm - **Markup***

[image]

*contactform_snippet.htm - **Code***

[image]

And below is the **Static Page** which I have created and used *contactform_snippet.htm* which I just created.

[image]

And below is *Preview* how its looking like.

[image]

The thing is, Even if I click on "Submit" button, it is not doing anything.

I also changed the form code from `data-request="{{ __SELF__ }}::onSendInquiry"` to `data-request="onSendInquiry"`but then I am getting below error saying:

> AJAX handler 'onSendInquiry' was not found.

The thing here is, similar thing I have created and copied in **CMS Page** instead of **Static Page** and all is working there with validations and email being sent.

So My question is how can make the same thing work in **Static Pages** here using **Snippets**. I know the can be achieved via creating **Components** but I have so many of forms and I want to implement something like this to make it work. Any thoughts what should I need to make this work here ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Guys, Eventually I made it work by putting my doing this `data-request="onSendInquiry"` in my form and putting below code in my **default.htm** layout file.

```
function onSendInquiry()
{
    // Collect input
    $name = post('name');
    $email = post('email');
    $subject = post('subject');
    $msg = post('msg');

    // Form Validation
    $validator = Validator::make(
        [
            'name' => $name,
            'email' => $email,
            'subject' => $subject,
            'msg' => $msg,
        ],
        [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'subject' => 'required',
            'msg' => 'required',
        ]
    );

    if ($validator->fails())
    {

        $messages = $validator->messages();
        throw new ApplicationException($messages->first());
        //Retrieving all error messages for all fields
        /*foreach ($messages->all() as $message) {
            throw new ApplicationException($message);
        }*/
        //throw new ApplicationException($messages);
    }


    // All is well -- Submit form
    $to = System\Models\MailSetting::get('sender_email');
    //$to = System\Models\MailSettings::get('sender_email');
    //$to = config('mail.from.address');
    //$to = 'mittul@technobrave.com';
    //die($to);
    $params = compact('name','email','subject','msg');
    Mail::sendTo($to, 'yourappname.website::mail.contactform', $params);
    return true;
}]
```

Was so close yet so far. Got it in the end. Thanks