# OctoberCMS from input to databse

Tags: octobercms

Can somebody tell me how can i make my contact input, or any other, save to my database? For octobercms
So I just want that when user type something in input file and click submit or something, to save it in my database in table i created?

Comment: See this thread - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43342871/custom-contact-form-in-partials-and-use-in-static-pages-plugin. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to create plugin

https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/registration

> Or you can use `plugin builder` to build plugin, basically its needed to create database table. [ https://octobercms.com/plugin/rainlab-builder ]

Then you need to create `cms page` for frontend, where you can add your markup for text box and button for submit.

> **Markup section**

```html
<!-- AJAX enabled form -->
<form data-request="onSubmitHandle" data-request-flash>
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <button type="submit">Submit Fire Ajax</button>
</form>
```

> **Code section**

```php
function onSubmitHandle()
{
    $validator = \Validator::make(        
        post(),
        ['email' => 'required']
    );

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        \Flash::error('Email Needed.');
    }
    else {
        $model = new \Author\PluginName\Models\MyModel;
        $model->email = post('email');
        $model->save();    
        \Flash::success('data saved.');
    }

}
```

> This code will check if email is entered it will save data to `model(database)` and show success message if email is not passed it will show error `email needed.`
>
> **To make Flash Messages work please add js libs as well** [ https://octobercms.com/docs/ajax/introduction ] you can follow this guide how to add them in your layout.

if you have any doubts please comment.

Comment: Okay so I created my plugin using builder, database table and contact page with form in markup and submit in code. What should i do next? I'm new at OctoberCMS and I don't know much. Please help.

Comment: in page there will be 2 section code & markup you need to add code there and you need to change it according to your need. [ php knowledge is needed for this ]